# algebraic numbers of degree 3 and 6, whose sum has degree 12

Tags: galois-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

This question is related to [Degree of sum of algebraic numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers). Forgive me if
this is a dumb question, but are there two algebraic numbers $a$ and $b$ of degree $3$ and $6$ respectively, such that the sum $a+b$ has degree $12$ ?

Intuitively it would seem that the degree of $a+b$ should divide $3 \times 6=18$, but I was unable to prove this. Hence my question.

Comment: Ewan, I changed mistaken tags "algebraic" and "numbers" by "algebraic # theory". The composite tags (like "algebraic numbers") use dash.

Comment: Ewan, I retagged galois-theory based on answers; and I don't really see what it has to do with commutative algebra. If I am mistaken on the second point, feel free to put it back. 

Comment:  @ Willie : I agree with you, although a non-galois-theoretic solution is not excluded a priori.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The splitting field $K$ of $x^6-2$ has degree 12 over the rationals. Its Galois group is the dihedral group 
$D_{12}$. This group has subgroups $A$ and $B$, where $A$ has order 2, $B$ has order 4, and $B$ does not contain 
$A$; the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$ together is all of $D_{12}$. Now let $E$ and $F$ be the fixed fields of $A$ and $B$ respectively; then $E$ has degree 6, $F$ has degree 3, and $F$ is not contained in $E$, so the smallest field containing both $E$ and $F$ is $K$. Now if you pick pretty much any $a$ in $F$ and pretty much any $b$ in $E$, you should have what you want.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example making Gerry's suggestion explicit (I was curious what an example would look like): $a = {\omega}2^{1/3}$, $b = 2^{1/6}$, where $\omega$ is a nontrivial cube root of unity. By PARI, $a + b$ has minimal polynomial 
$$
x^{12} - 8x^9 + 18x^8 + 12x^7 + 20x^6 - 72x^5 + 276x^4 - 232x^3 + 180x^2 + 24x + 4.
$$

Without giving it a lot of thought, you might think the minimal polynomial might be something like 
$$
((x-2^{1/3})^6-2)((x - {\omega}2^{1/3})^6-2)((x - {\omega}^22^{1/3})^6-2)
$$
and this polynomial of degree 18 does have rational coefficients, but it factors as
$$
(x^6 - 4x^3 - 18x^2 - 12x + 2)
(x^{12} - 8x^9 + 18x^8 + 12x^7 + 20x^6 - 72x^5 + 276x^4 - 232x^3 + 180x^2 + 24x + 4).
$$
Yes, the second factor is the polynomial above.  The multiplicative relations among 
$a$ and $b$ account for such breaking up.

Comment:  Another way to see it is that $X^6-2$, the annihilator of $a$, factors 
as $(X-b^2)(X^2+b^2X-b^4)$. The minimal polynomial of $a$ over
${\mathbb Q}(b)$ is $X^2+b^2X-b^4$. So the degree of $a$ over
${\mathbb Q}(b)$ is 2. 

Comment: @Ewan: Your comment isn't another way, by itself, to see the degree is 12, since the degree of $a$ over ${\mathbf Q}(b)$ does not on its own tell you the degree of $a+b$ over ${\mathbf Q}$, which is what your question was about. The point is that ${\mathbf Q}(a+b)$ need not be ${\mathbf Q}(a,b)$. For example, let $r$ and $s$ be two roots of $x^4+8x+12$. Both $r$ and $s$ have degree 4 over ${\mathbf Q}$ and $r$ has degree 3 over ${\mathbf Q}(s)$, but $r+s$ has degree 6, not 12, over ${\mathbf Q}$. In your case, ${\mathbf Q}(a+b) = {\mathbf Q}(a,b)$, but that needs to be checked separately.